# "Hamdi is very fast I think he will win the match"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between

> Hamdi is very fast I think he will win the match

and

> Hamdi is running fast, I think he is going to win the race

is that only running and very fast or this is not a difference?

Comment: "Hamdi is very fast" relies on your knowing what Hamdi is doing. Is he running a foot race? Is he on a game show requiring quick mental feats? Is he a race driver?

Answer (score 2):

> Hamdi is very fast

is a general statement about Hamdi. Hamdi could be sitting on his couch when you say this about him. It is roughly equivalent to "historically, Hamdi has been known to run fast, and if he were to start running right now, I believe he would run quickly"

> Hamdi is running fast

is a statement about Hamdi's current state. Hamdi is currently running, and he is running quickly. I would only say "Hamdi is running fast" if I was watching Hamdi participating in a race or something.

Comment: But how do you know this is about running? We could be watching Hamdi in a hamburger eating competition.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie - you know its about running when it says "hamdi is running".  You don't know its' about running if its not mentioned.